# Why does my java project in GCP can't create entityManagerFactory?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, google-cloud-platform

I've uploaded a java spring-boot project to GCP. When I enter the server's url in the browser, I get status code 500. I checked the error reporting in GCP and this is what I see (MovieTown is the project's name):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/AbstractBeanFactory.java:335 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/AbstractBeanFactory.java:333 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean ( org/springframework.beans.factory.support/AbstractBeanFactory.java:208 )
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean ( org/springframework.context.support/AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154 )
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization ( org/springframework.context.support/AbstractApplicationContext.java:908 )
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh ( org/springframework.context.support/AbstractApplicationContext.java:583 )
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh ( org/springframework.boot.web.servlet.context/ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147 )
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh ( org/springframework.boot/SpringApplication.java:734 )
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext ( org/springframework.boot/SpringApplication.java:408 )
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run ( org/springframework.boot/SpringApplication.java:308 )
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run ( org/springframework.boot/SpringApplication.java:1306 )
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run ( org/springframework.boot/SpringApplication.java:1295 )
at com.MovieTown.MovieTownApplication.main ( com/MovieTown/MovieTownApplication.java:15 )
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ( jdk/internal.reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77 )
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ( jdk/internal.reflect/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 )
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke ( java/lang.reflect/Method.java:568 )
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run ( org/springframework.boot.loader/MainMethodRunner.java:49 )
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch ( org/springframework.boot.loader/Launcher.java:108 )
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch ( org/springframework.boot.loader/Launcher.java:58 )
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main ( org/springframework.boot.loader/JarLauncher.java:65 )
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException

at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService ( AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275 )
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService ( AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237 )
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService ( AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214 )
at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices ( DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175 )
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies ( AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286 )
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService ( AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243 )
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService ( AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214 )
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init> ( InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173 )
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete ( MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127 )
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata ( EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460 )
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build ( EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494 )
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory ( SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58 )
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory ( LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365 )
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory ( AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409 )
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet ( AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396 )
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet ( LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods ( AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863 )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean ( AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800 )


…
```

I've already created a mySQL instance. I also changed the application.properties so my project will connect to it, and when I run my project locally, it connects to it successfully.

Did I miss something or did something wrong?

Comment: you'll need to show more of the stacktrace

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: I've added the the full stacktrace. I'll be glad for help